# Installing Ubuntu in Windows 7 virtual PC

Tags: windows-7, installation, ubuntu-10.04

I am trying to install Ubuntu Desktop (latest edition downloaded from their website) on my Windows 7 Virtual PC. The VM boots and I get to the install screen, however, when I press ENTER to begin the installation, the VM shutsdown.

I have an XP VM running fine on the same machine.

Am I missing something or UBUNTU is not supported?

I am running

Windows 7 Ultimate 32bit
AMD Phenom 9600QUAD Core 2300
X86-based PC
4 GB Memory

Comment: 32 or 64-bit version of Ubuntu? Win7 Virtual PC only supports 32-bit.

Comment: The chap has said he is using 32bit windows7! - I experienced the same issue, the issue is also apparnt when trying to use Fedora Core 13 - I would be very gratefull if someone has found a fix for this!

Comment: The 32-bit version I am trying to install.

Comment: Why would someone vote to close?...where would I find a solution? I've exhausted all my leads before posting here.

Comment: I presume you've read through all the discussion on installing Ubuntu on Windows 7 Virtual PC at http://nemesisv.blogspot.com/2009/04/installing-ubuntu-904-on-microsoft.html

Comment: I found some info on superuser.com...I switch from Virtual PC to Virtual Box (can I transfer my current VMs to VirtualBox?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like some people have success and some don't. You can try (from [here](http://smudj.wordpress.com/2009/11/06/ubuntu-9-10-works-under-windows-vpc/)):

```
On the first screen, choose [English].
Press [F4] and select [Safe Graphics].
Press [F6], press [Escape].
From the command line:
Remove “quiet splash –”
replace ”vga=791 noreplace-paravirt” without the quotes.
Press [Enter] to start the installation.
```

From the Wikipedia entry on [Windows Virtual PC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Virtual_PC)

> As of Windows Virtual PC, Linux guests are not officially supported. Linux additions are supported in Microsoft Virtual Server, and these additions should also work in Virtual PC.[35]
>   Some Linux distributions must be installed in text mode, as Microsoft Virtual PC only emulates graphics at 16-bit or 32-bit color depth, not 24-bit.Ubuntu 8.10 (Intrepid Ibex) must be installed in SafeMode, but does not require other changes.

Answer (score 1):

Is Virtual PC an absolute requirement?  If not, use Oracle's brilliant (and free) [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).