# Crash / disappearing VM when starting Ubuntu 10.04 installation CD in Windows Virtual PC

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, microsoft-virtual-pc

When I attempt to start the Ubuntu 10.04 installation/live CD in Windows Virtual PC, the VM window just disappears every time during boot just after showing the mostly blank startup splash screen (with the keyboard and accessibility logos at the bottom).

How can I start the Ubuntu 10.04 Desktop or Netbook installation/live CD in Windows Virtual PC?

Comment: Mark as duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/157821 , which apparently isn't indexed by Google yet.

Comment: Please mark as duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derived from 9.04 directions at http://nemesisv.blogspot.com/2009/04/installing-ubuntu-904-on-microsoft.html:

1. Boot Ubuntu up. On the first screen, choose [English].
2. Then press <kbd>F6</kbd>, but do not select any options.
3. Instead press <kbd>ESC</kbd> - it will allow you to change the command line.
4. Remove the option `quiet splash --` and replace it with `vga=791 noreplace-paravirt` instead.
5. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to start the installation.

Comment: Also, once you get it installed, you might want this: http://superuser.com/questions/61708

Comment: nice one, it just worked for me!!